# IIS7 Application Pool Crash

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2008, application-pool

I am running IIS 7.0 on Windows server 2008 R2 and created 1 Application Pool per site and I have 1 site which is causing the application pool to stop. These are the following errors in the Event Viewer:

**This shows several times:**

A process serving application pool 'Pilot.Mobile.SyncV2' terminated unexpectedly. The process id was '3620'. The process exit code was '0x80131506'.

**Then I get this:**

Application pool 'Pilot.Mobile.SyncV2' is being automatically disabled due to a series of failures in the process(es) serving that application pool.

Two Things- How can I findout why this is crashing e.g. tools or scritps, also has anyone get any scripts I can run on a schedule task that will check the application pools and if 1 is down it will restart it and email me.

Comment: Your question is likely to receive better answers on http://serverfault.com/ - nominating the question for automatic migration.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a list of ["Useful tools and add-ons for IIS troubleshooting and IIS7"](http://blogs.msdn.com/dougste/archive/2008/05/16/useful-tools-and-add-ons-for-iis-troubleshooting-and-iis7.aspx).

Tess Ferrandez (ASP.NET Escalation Engineer at Microsoft) has a [good blog on debugging](http://blogs.msdn.com/tess/).

I don't have any scripts to give you. We use [Nagios](http://www.nagios.org)/[OpsView](http://www.opsview.org) to monitor websites/servers and notify us.